# Hit Servlet with radio button selection without submit button

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I am creating a web application where I want to pass the selection done by radio button to controller.Now,I want this action to be performed without submit button.I googled a lot but did'nt get the way to do this without submit button.

here is the HTML Code for this requirement

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/env" method="post">
    QA71<input type="radio" name="env" value="QA71" checked="checked">
    QA72<input type="radio" name="env" value="QA72" >
    </form>
```

Here is the code of java for this requirement

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/env", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String env(HttpServletRequest request){

        logger.info("parameter is "+request.getParameter("env"));
        return "home";

    }
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can send the value via javascript/ajax.

Comment: Could you please provide me code for that?

Comment: Sure, You can check this [link](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/), will give you better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a submit button you should use javascript to submit the form one way to do that is:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

so first you need to put an id attribute to your form, and second you need to decide in what event you want to submit the form in this example I chose on blur of the second radio:

```
<form id="myForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/env" method="post">
    QA71<input type="radio" name="env" value="QA71" checked="checked">
    QA72<input type="radio" name="env" value="QA72" onBlur="submitForm()">
</form>

function submitForm() {
     document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```